# How change a WordPress message and add a hyperlink into the message

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

In some existing WordPress/wooCommerce php custom code is this expression:

```
...
public function change_message( $message ) {
        return __( 'Your order is too heavy. Please contact us to get individual shipping cost' );
    }
...
```

How/can the text "contact us" be changed into a hyperlink/button.
Or another way of asking the question is can it contain HTML?

Comment: _"Or another way of asking the question is can it contain HTML?"_ - impossible to tell, based on just that snippet you have shown us. All this does is manipulate a string value that will be used somewhere else, but we don't know how it will get treated in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprintf function and create a variable to simplify your code, like this

```
...
public function change_message( $message ) {
        $contact_us = __('contact us');
        $link = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">'.$contact_us.'</a>';
        $format = __('Your order is too heavy. Please %s to get individual shipping cost');
        return sprintf($format, $link);
    }
...
```

Comment: This is close: there should be translation on "contact us" in the link.

Comment: You'se right @Caleb I just updated my code

Comment: Thank you both. It works!, so now I can move on to develop/improve the whole UI.